# How to remove a permission added because of Google Fitness API 7.5.0

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

After updating my play-services-fitness api from 7.0.0 to 7.5.0 I noticed that when I go to upload a new build to the PlayStore it tells me that I am adding a new permission and 2 new features. I did not do this! What the heck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some research to pin down the culprit it was in fact play-services-fitness:7.5.0 that was to blame. By including that in your project (`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.5.0'`) and compiling it will inject the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>` into your AndroidManifest.xml. So the PlayStore is correct, you are asking to use new permissions and features. You can confirm this by checking your build/intermediaries/manifests/full/[debug|release]/AndroidManifest.xml file. There you will see the new permission added. To remove this you simply add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />` to your own manifest and it will be stripped out during the manifest merge process.
You will crash if/when you do use a Fitness API that requires that permission but if you can guarantee that you won't use it then there you have it.

Comment: For me it also added the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission which I removed the same way. Even though I don't know which SDK features might rely on that permission, but disabling it didn't cause any problems, yet.